# How do I get the Timeline of an Allure report to display fixtures?

Tags: pytest, fixtures, allure

While the Allure timeline is great for visualizing the various threads of my suite, it's impossible to tell if the gaps between my Pytest tests are due to setup fixtures or teardown fixtures, and so I don't know where to look to make my tests more efficient.

In the following screenshot of my timeline, the white gaps between tests are either setup or teardown - but there's no way to know which.

[image: Allure timeline with fixture gaps]

Is there a setting within any configuration file which would result in Allure displaying fixtures either as part of the test execution or as a separate entity in the timeline?